# How to prove that there are no integers a,b such that $b^2=4a+2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

How to prove that there are no integers a,b such that $b^2=4a+2$

This seems like a very simple prof but when i tried to work through it i keep on hitting walls.
 I tried to prove this by contradiction saying that suppose there exists an $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}:b^2=4a+2$

then i worked through the proof as different cases, when a and b is odd, a,b is even and a is odd and b is even but i cant seem to get the answer.

Comment: How rigorous does the proof have to be?  Is it enough to say that $b^2$ would be a multiple of $2$, but not $4$?

Comment: For every integer $N$, we have $N^2\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$.

Comment: should be a formal proof @mike but i get what you are saying and that makes sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $b$ is odd then so is $b^2$, which is absurd since $4a+2$ is even.

If $b$ is even, say $b=2k$ we get $4k^2=4a+2$ hence $4(k^2-a)=2$, hence $2$ is a multiple of $4$, which is absurd.

Comment: thanks that makes a lot of sense !